# Python Regex to capture @[123456](John Smith)

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to capture the id and name in a pattern like this @[123456](John Smith) and use those to create a string like < a href="123456"> John Smith< /a>.

Here's what I tried, but it's not working.

```
def format(text):

    def idrepl(match):
        fbid = match.group(1)
        name = match.group(2)
        print fbid, name
        return '<a href="https://www.facebook.com/{}">{}</a>'.format(fbid, name)

    return re.sub(r'\@\[(\d+)\]\[(\w\s+)\]', idrepl, text)
```

Comment: your regex does not match your input. According to your regex,you are trying to match `@[123456][John Smith]`, not  `@[123456](John Smith)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part

```
(\w\s+)
```

matches exactly one word character followed by 1+ whitespace characters.

Clearly that's **not** what you want, and it's easy to fix:

```
([\w\s]+)
```

"one or more characters each of which is a word or whitespace char".

Whether that's **actually** what you want, I'm not sure -- it **will** happily match `John Smith`, but **not** e.g `Maureen O'Hara` (that apostrophe will impede the match) or `John V. Smith` (here, it's the dot what will impede the match) or `John Smith-Passell` (here, it's the dash).

In general, people spell their names with potentially several punctuation characters (as well as word-characters and whitespace) -- apostrophes, dots, dashes, and more.  If you don't need to account for this, then, fine!-)  If you **do**, life gets a bit harder (sticking those chars within the square brackets above will mostly do, but precautions are needed -- e.g a dash, if you need it to be part of the bracketed char set, must be at the end, just before the close bracket).